# I am uncertain what to use as a light source to expose the photoresis for PCB making

Tags: pcb

I want to graduate from toner transfer method of PCB making to using photoresist.
I may be making a bigger deal of this than needed, but I am unclear on what I need to use to efficiently and effectively expose photoresist film when making DIY PCB's.  Someone said that I need high UV, but not sure how to find that. A lot of the grow lights I see say "no UV".  Any help?

Comment: What does the photoresist you use specify?

Comment: What is the type of photo resist you intend to use? The exposure depends probably on it.

Comment: The Sun is pretty bright[citation needed] and has an emission spectrum that overlaps the absorption of any kind of photoresist.

Comment: Chances are you can use special fluorescent tubes or UV LEDs. Other less attractive options are Hg or carbon arc.  There are several types of the former depending on the wavelength required (generally speaking, the shorter the wavelength the more expensive and hazardous the source). Find out the wavelength (usually specified in nm) required.

Comment: @Phil Frost: I remember buying pre-conditioned clad PCB material some time ago. The instructions were "expose to a UV source at a distance of 3 to 6 inches for 5 minutes or to bright sunlight for 20 minutes at a distance of approximately 93 million miles".

Comment: No one is saying it, but I'm pretty sure when I did photoresist hobby boards (before I graduated to toner transfer) I exposed them in a box with several ordinary fluorescent tubes for 15-30 minutes. The phosphors in these tubes don't convert all the ultraviolet and deep violet light from the inter mercury arc, so you just have to make up for the "inefficiency" with power and time. I've heard of people using 500W halogen lamps also, provided they don't have a UV filter.

Comment: Phil Frost:  May I ask what caused you to choose toner transfer over photoresists?  I have been doing toner transfer for a while now with pretty good success, but find that I end up using wider traces than I need to compensate for inconsistancy in the transfer.  I hoped that photoresists would be more precise.  Would you disagree with that?

Comment: You could buy a professional UV exposure box, which are quite expensive, or make your own using exactly the same UV tubes, eg. [Rapid Online 2 x 15W UV tubes and starters](https://www.rapidonline.com/mega-electronics-34-0709-2-x-15w-tubes-and-starters-set-34-0709) and a timer. You need to calibrate the exposure time, which is quite critical. Look at the 'Related' questions to the right to get advice on calibration.

Answer (score 7):

As others note, light required may vary with resist type, but many (or most) use UV and a germicidal UV lamp is usually very adequate (as is longer sunlight exposure).

Germicidal lamps are usually fluorescent like tubes but with no phosphor so the UV is not converted to visible light. As Spehro says, they will happily damage your eyes (my wife spent several days with BOTH eyes bandaged after UV from such a tube was diffracted into an unexpected location. (Not her fault.))
BUT I have used them often (for resist exposure and for product testing) with due care and no problems. A quick occasional glance is usually acceptable BUT do read up on your tube ratings and exposure times and distances.

You want reasonably even exposure so for very large boards you may need multiple tubes. A folded CFL type lamp gives a broader light sources in a single package.
Right hand two tubes here are UV. ( [from here](http://quartz_tube.china-direct-buy.com/v/4/product_detail/5247115/Quartz_UV_Germicidal_Lamp_Special-shape.html) )

[image]

Many examples of germicidal lamps are available [**here**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=germicidal+lamp&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj35bnNy8jPAhWDGJQKHX62CxMQ_AUICCgB&biw=1745&bih=973)

Genuine shortwavelength UV LEDs are becoming more common but are usually costly per UV output compared to 'fluorescent" type devices.
Allegedly "UV" LEDS at lower cost are available but are almost always unsuitable as they are either very "near UV" so lower quanta of energy in each photon or really just deep blue with about no UV.

What country are you in?
You can probably get suitable lamps on ebay or selected retail outlets.

Many ebay germicidal lamps [**here**](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=germicidal+lamp&rt=nc&LH_BIN=1) - most but not all are genuinely short wavelength UV.

This is an example of an [**unsuitable lamp**](http://www.ebay.com/itm/E27-UV-25W30W40W-220V-Blacklight-Low-Energy-Light-Bulb-Screw-Germicidal-Lamp-/131864693462?var=&hash=item1eb3bf8ad6:m:mdlxWsM6VCACaDcLaGsBlRg) on sale on ebay and sourced from Hong Kong. While they claim it to be a germicidal lamp it is a longer wavelength "black light" lamp.  The dark glass and purple-blue output show it is NOT a short wavelength lamp (or largely not).

[image]

The good oil.  Typical appearance.
Clear glass - a major indicator.
Some visible blue/purple. Visible component Low for wattage.

Do not stare at lamp with remaining good eye !

[image]

**Safety:**

I do not wish to discourage people with safety aspects or overemphasise the risk. I'm less careful than some people in many areas (ie  I'm an engineer) but stay aware of the risk factors. I have glanced at an eg 15 Watt germicidal UV tube at distances of maybe 500-1000 mm on numerous occasions but only for a brief moment and perhaps a few times on most uses. I have NEVER had any eye problems as a result.
But I have had mild "snow blindness" from UV exposure while skiing (long ago) so know what the results are like.

I am not a doctor / YMMV / All care but YOUR responsibility:

Instant blindness will NOT occur with lamps normally encountered - over exposure will initially lead to sore eyes, then inflammation and VERY sore eyes. This is the same as 'snow blindness' experienced when skiing at altitude for excessively long periods without goggles. I am assured by medical experts that exposure to levels that make your eyes unusable for several days but not grossly worse than that  (as in my wife's case) are NOT a threat to the retina, as one may expect them to be. I have reasons to doubt this opinion, but too complex/detailed/irrelevant for this forum.

Requirement for sore eyes - Guesstimate only: probably a few 10's of seconds in a day at 500 mm+ with tubes of under 30 Watts. I'd never get anywhere near that level.

Comment: Wow, i feel so....informed.  thank you.  This answered questions that i would not have known to ask.

Comment: Russell, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photokeratitis is about the cornea, not about the retina. It's *cornea sunburn*, and very painful due to the open nerve endings the cornea has. Your wife most likely is more susceptible to dermal pain than you and for touches, too. For the latter, lucky you.

Comment: @Janka Yes. I agree about what the Wikipedia article is about AND in fact that's consistent with my statement. As I said - too complex/detailed/irrelevant to have gone into detail here. BUT to explain why I mentioned the retina  when my wife was taken to the local hospital which is probably the centre of medical eye excellence in NZ the doctor inspected her eye in a "here's another day job job" way (professional but business as usual) THEN leaped up and ran out of the room and called in a colleague. Excitement was evident (I'm told, I was in China alas or I'd have been there. They both got ...

Comment: Excitement? As in Scrubs? I expect a doctor mourning all time as in Dr. House. [^.^;]

Comment: @Janka  ... suitable excited "and we were off". She was "also" suffering from an epiretinal membrane which was threatening retinal separation and needed urgent ["Epiretinal peel" surgery](http://www.aao.org/focalpointssnippetdetail.aspx?id=af56d760-dd05-4399-ad95-b26636f5fc0c). This involves [removal of the vitreous gel in the eye interior](http://www.eyeinstitute.co.nz/eye-surgery/epiretinal-membrane-surgery.htm)  and surgical action of the retinal surface. Nowadays a reasonably safe and usually successful procedure. She was told that in a small % of case glaucoma may follow - Murphy ...

Comment: ... ensured that in her case it did - but subsequent LASER ablation "cured" this. || The main point though is that the eye experts are absolutely sure that the UV damage to the corneas did NOT cause the retinal damage and that this was just a lucky find so the UV damage was a most fortuitous happening. BUT I did very extensive reading across the subject and based on some welding burn cases where "impossible" retinal damage was denied but about 99% certainly occurred I think it reasonably possible in this unusual case that the UV MAY have been the cause. All ended up well though, regardless.

Comment: Happy to hear that.